# Getting code behind to work in Cesium environment

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cesiumjs

I am trying to add an asp gridview to a page where I have a Cesium map being displayed. The problem I am having is trying to get the code behind that I want to use to fill the grid to work. If I put the normal code behind line

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="CesiumGrid" %>
```

in at the beginning it shows up as text at the top of the webpage. The code never gets called, and I assume that it has something to do with the Cesium environment I am running in.

Does anyone know how to get Cesium and code behind to work together? I need to run SQL Server queries, so if there is a better way to do it with Cesium, please let me know (with examples - I am new to all of this).

Answer (score 0):

This type of ASP.NET page typically works by POSTing the user's changes back to the server, and allowing the server to regenerate new HTML code to send to the page.  This isn't a great fit for Cesium, which depends on the existing HTML and in particular the existing WebGL canvas to stay in place, and not be destroyed and recreated with every PostBack event.

If you want to stay in the .NET family, you could look at Web API.  The most similar example offered by the Cesium project is in the czml-writer library (and disclaimer, I wrote the initial version of this example some years ago).  It's called the [ExampleCesiumLanguageServer](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/tree/master/DotNet/ExampleCesiumLanguageServer).  This example uses a static HTML page to display a Cesium globe, and then uses Cesium's own helper functions to call back into the .NET server and ask for information to display on the globe.

There are 3rd-party JS libraries (too numerous to list here) that could be used to display and update a grid alongside this globe, and communicate with the server without causing full page reloads or damage to the existing WebGL canvas.